# How to connect via SSH to different Qemu instances

Tags: ssh, qemu, port-forwarding

I want to connect from my local laptop to remote desktop (let say `170.170.70.70`) with two Qemu instances started with parameters (most parameters skipped, I left only those that differs)

1. `qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev tap,id=net0 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::4444-:22 -vnc :0`
2. `qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev tap,id=net1 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -vnc :1`

When I do `sudo netstat -ltnup|grep qemu` on remote desktop I get

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1305730/qemu-system 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1306061/qemu-system 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1306061/qemu-system 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1305730/qemu-system 
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      1305730/qemu-system 
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN      1306061/qemu-system
```

Using `vncviewer` I can access UI of each Qemu instance from my local laptop with

```
vncviewer 170.170.70.70::5900  # First instance
vncviewer 170.170.70.70::5901  # Second instance
```

But I want to be able to connect via SSH as well. And when I do

```
ssh jason@170.170.70.70  # Connect to remote
ssh root@192.168.7.2  # Connect to Qemu
```

I connect to firs one. I thought that due to port forwarding I'll be able to connect as

```
ssh root@192.168.7.2 -p 4444 # First instance
ssh root@192.168.7.2 -p 5555 # Second instance
```

But that didn't work, I got

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 4444: Connection refused
```

What I need to change to be able to connect via SSH to both Qemu instances?

Comment: Is the SSH server actually running on those instances?

Comment: @raj how can I check this? I can connect to first, so I guess it should be running on both...

Comment: wouldn't it be `ssh root@170.170.70.70 -p 4444` ? And you should not allow root login anyhow. It is disabled by default.

Comment: @JaSON From what you write I understand you can't connect to neither port 4444 nor 5555, so what does "I can connect to first" mean? Also, as Doug Smythies pointed out, where does the IP address 192.168.7.2 come from, if your IP address is 170.170.70.70 ?

Comment: @raj "I can connect to first" means that I can connect using default 22 port with `ssh root@192.168.7.2`. The IP of remote Ubuntu is 170.170.70.70 while IP of Qemu that started on that remote Ubuntu is 192.168.7.2 (default Qemu IP).

Comment: P.S. Probably the fact that Qemu is located on remote machine is not that important and I could say that I'm trying to connect Qemu directly, but I thought it worth to be mentioned

Comment: @JaSON If you are able to connect to first VM using IP address 192.168.7.2 it means that this is the IP address of the first VM. So what is the IP address of the second VM? You should use that to connect.

Comment: @raj if I do `sudo ss -ltnup` I see an entry for each new Qemu instance (I believe so): `192.168.7.1:123              0.0.0.0:*       users:(("ntpd",pid=1401,fd=24))`; `192.168.7.3:123              0.0.0.0:*       users:(("ntpd",pid=1401,fd=25))`; 
`192.168.7.5:123              0.0.0.0:*       users:(("ntpd",pid=1401,fd=26))`... but `ssh root@192.168.7.4` doesn't work as well (I get `No route to host`). So the problem is to find exact IP or port number for each new instance...